# Headless Android Testing, Process files without interacting with UI Components

Tags: android, android-testing

I am trying to make an android application that processes CSV files with basic data and outputs processed data in an easily scannable/readable format. I am having difficulty finding a headless testing process through which I can run all the background processes that an individual would normally perform by clicking on the UI components, without actually touching the UI components or an emulator. I can handle the final verification, but I am unsure how to handle the automation process without the GUI. I don't want the testing to interact with the GUI.

I first thought of simply using the JAR files instead of the Android code since my initial perception of my goal was that the goal was to test the processing as if there was no visual Android component. But in reality, Android acts like a wrapper so it wouldn't be truly testing user flow: so I can't just take out the android part. Another way I am exploring is using the emulator with my Application installed in the same manner as using a server--that way I can perhaps run the methods directly without actually clicking the buttons. But even that I feel like I'm spouting nonsense. I hope I've framed the question well.

I am familiar with UI Automator and Espresso, and they are, unfortunately, not what I want due to the necessity of having test code written to be internally within the Application code and also the need of the UI components.

Is there a preferred method of doing this?

Comment: have you considered [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Activity Testing/Service Testing links from Google. You can write JUnit test against your application. if you want to test a user scenario you can design your test case to call all function in same sequence.

- make sure to introduce some wait time between interactions to simulate real user

https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html
https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/service_testing.html